# Tips for breaking into domain brokering?

Tags: seo, domains

As a web developer I consider myself fairly familiar with SEO and website structure in terms of advising clients where there is room for improvement and such, however recently a client of mine asked me to broker what appears to be a fairly high value domain (I'm estimating fair market value of +$1k because it's dot com era concise & simple) however I'm not sure how to go about being the broker.

In particular I'm wondering what is the best way to valuate the domain and leverage the information during a negotiation. For example when a website is in the mix, you at least can check the SEO, rankings, etc. but as this is a plain domain name which is not used I'm not sure where to pull data.

Aside from checking domain sales and auctions for similar domains to get a ballpark fair market value, are there any other tactics I can use? Are paid appraisal services helpful at all? Is there a way to do them myself?

As I'm planning to turn this into a new company service, any referrals to tips and websites on the topic are greatly appreciated.